# Why is the background of my plot black when I use plot_gg() from Rayshader in R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, rayshader

I am trying to represent some point data for a region in 3D using the Rayshader package. It plots everything correctly, except that the background is totally black. How to fix this? Below is my code:

```
base_map <- ggplot(data = df.shp, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(color = "#8a8a8a", fill = "#8a8a8a") +
  coord_quickmap() +
  theme_void()

growing_stock = base_map +
  geom_point(data = temp1, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color=volume_per_ha, group=time),size=2) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(name = 'Average growing stock [m3/ha]', 
                        limits=range(temp1$volume_per_ha), 
                        low="#FCB9B2", high="#B23A48")  
growing_stock

plot_gg(growing_stock, width=5, height=5, multicore = TRUE, scale = 300)
```

Here is how the plot looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to fix this. Removing `theme_void`, or replacing it with one of other themes can change the background color, but will add some other `ggplot2` components to the graph that you may not want. One easy way to fix the problem is just to explicitly change the background color using `theme()`.

```
base_map <- ggplot(data = df.shp, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "#8a8a8a", fill = "#8a8a8a") +
  coord_quickmap() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(
      fill = "white",
      colour = "white"
    )
  )
```

I changed background color to "white" in this example. You may want to change to another color.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It's an OS problem.

Same code:
-theme_void() + macOS = no black square
-theme_void() + windows = black square around the plot

I think the first answer is the only solution for now. It blends a little better if you change the shadowcolor in plot_gg() to be the same as the lightcolor in renderhighquality().